# python error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to get the variable `stop_date` to take away the value from the variable `start_date` to get the return output as `30`.

When I try this:

```
start_date = '20151231171500'
stop_date = '20151231174500'
test = stop_date - start_date
print test
```

It give me an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

The error are jumping on this line:

```
test = stop_date - start_date
```

I am trying to convert from date format into the minutes for the remaining time.

Comment: How can u subtract from strings ?

Comment: @Padriac: surely we can find a dupe that deals with datetime info instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start_date` and `stop_date` are strings, which don't support the `-` operator. If you want to compute their (numerical) difference, define them as integers, i.e.

```
start_date = 20151231171500
stop_date = 20151231174500
```

or cast them to `int`:

```
test = int(stop_date) - int(start_date)
```

Caveat: the difference of these numbers would be 3000, not 30. Not sure why you expect 30.

*edit*: so much for why you cannot substract a string from a string. To compute the actual time difference between dates, please see Martijn's answer.

Comment: They are not integers though. They are *dates*. Treating the strings as integers will give you the wrong results; the difference is 1800 seconds, not 3000.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right of course, I did not catch that. I left an edit message pointing to your answer because it better addresses what the asker *actually* wants.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, how I can remove the two zero at the end `00` after the first two value to make it return as `30`?

Comment: @David: you are being unclear in your question. You expect to treat the two values as a date-and-time, and want to know the difference between them in minutes. The answer to that question is indeed *30*, but by correctly naming what you are doing you get your answers faster.

Answer (score 4):

You have strings, not datetime objects. If you want to treat the strings as datetime information, you'll need to parse them into `datetime` objects:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
stop_date = datetime.strptime(stop_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

difference = stop_date - start_date
```

The resulting objects is a [`datetime.timedelta()` instance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta), which models a time duration in terms of days and seconds:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> start_date = '20151231171500'
>>> stop_date = '20151231174500'
>>> start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
>>> stop_date = datetime.strptime(stop_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
>>> start_date, stop_date
(datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31, 17, 15), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31, 17, 45))
>>> difference = stop_date - start_date
>>> difference
datetime.timedelta(0, 1800)
>>> difference.seconds
1800
```

Printing a `timedelta` object formats it to show days (if there are any), hours, minutes and seconds:

```
>>> print difference
0:30:00
```

or you can calculate the number of minutes by dividing by 60. If you use the [`divmod()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) you get the remainder in seconds as well:

```
>>> minutes, seconds = divmod(difference.seconds, 60)
>>> minutes, seconds
(30, 0)
```

Do the same again with the `minutes` you calculated like this to get hours:

```
>>> hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
>>> hours, minutes, seconds
(0, 30, 0)
```

Note that you would use the [`timedelta.total_seconds()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to include the days as well, if you wanted to record the total number of hours over 24.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, how I can remove the two zero at the end `00` after the first two value `30` to make it return as `30`?

Comment: @David: I added how to calculate hours and minutes from the delta already. Do be precise in your question, you are looking for the difference in *minutes*.